# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in line 23

Tags: php, mysql, websocket, xampp, composer-php

when I run this line

```
$sql = $_db->query("UPDATE users SET theyear= '1999' WHERE UserName='batman'");
```

I get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in line 23
```

I using ratchet lib and php to changing value on database row if user connected to server the code can find the database table with out any proplem but when it come to editing value line I get this error

the database connectToDB.php code

```
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "test";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "";

// database connection
try{
    $_db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass, array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8", 
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
                )); 
}catch(Excepion $e){
    die("ERROR : ".$e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

the php code to edit the row value

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;

include('/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/classes/user.php');
include('/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/connectToDB.php');

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    global $_db;

        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";



       $sql = $_db->query("UPDATE users SET theyear= '1999' WHERE UserName='batman'");

    }
```

the composer.json code

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyApp": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.3.6",
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.3.6"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your database object is null. There is a problem in your connection string.

Comment: @ChipDean how but i tried to use it with out ratchet and the editing line worked with out any proplems ?

Comment: Do you have <?php in start of the connectToDB.php file?

Comment: The error states your connection object is null. It's either your connection string or an issue with the file istelf.

Comment: @ChipDean yes i have i mean sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$r = $_db->prepare("your query here");
$r->execute();
```

this will work

Comment: i get this error PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare()

Comment: <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxx";

try{
 $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=xxxx", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
    }

check your connection

Comment: i get MyApp\PDO' not found

Comment: i fixed that MyApp\PDO' not found

Comment: but i get new error PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _db in in this line $sql = $_db->prepare("my query")

Comment: change $_db to $con

Comment: i get this error o.O PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: con

Comment: $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass, array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8", 
     PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
                ));

Comment: i was forget to change $_db in db connection to $con so i changed it and now i get this error PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); write this on top of ur code

Comment: iget PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: con and PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare()

Comment: variable con is not used replace all $_db to $con

Comment: ok i added global $con; and the error gone and i get that only now PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare()

Comment: connectToDB.php dont use this try direct connection write new connection in ur page

Comment: If his `$_db` object is `null` this won't change anything. And why is this answer accepted? From the comments I don't see this being solved.